# Swift RestKit Post not including post data

Tags: swift, post, restkit

I'm not able to get data posted using the following code.  I've tried all related posts on SO but still can't get it to work.

Added in request descriptor, have the NSDictionary for mapping the parameters, tried inverseMapping, ect.

```
var parms = WearRequestParms()
parms.Height = height
parms.Width = width
parms.Density = density
if let userId = AlpineMetricsHttpClient.GetUserId()
{
     parms.UserId = userId
}

var objectManager : RKObjectManager?
objectManager = AlpineMetricsHttpClient.SetupClient()

// var mapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass:WearRequestParms.self)
var mapping = RKObjectMapping.requestMapping()

let requestMappingObjects =  ["IsCircle","Height","Width","Density","UserId","WearModel","Platform"]

let dict : NSMutableDictionary = ["IsCircle":"IsCircle","Height":"Height","Width":"Width","Density":"Density","UserId":"UserId","WearModel":"WearModel","Platform":"Platform"]

mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(requestMappingObjects)
// mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(dict as [NSObject : AnyObject])

// var newRequestMapping =  mapping.inverseMapping()

let requestDescriptor = RKRequestDescriptor(mapping: mapping, objectClass: WearRequestParms.self, rootKeyPath: "", method: RKRequestMethod.POST)

objectManager!.addRequestDescriptor(requestDescriptor)

// response
let responseMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass:PostStatus.self)

var responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(
    mapping: responseMapping
    ,method:RKRequestMethod.POST
    ,pathPattern : "/api/User/RegisterWearDevice"
    ,keyPath :""
    ,statusCodes  :  NSIndexSet(index:200))

objectManager!.addResponseDescriptor(responseDescriptor)

RKObjectManager.sharedManager().postObject(parms, path: "/api/User/RegisterWearDevice", parameters: nil,
    success:{ operation, mappingResult in
        NSLog("success")

        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "WearDimensionsSynced")

    },
    failure:{ operation, error in
        NSLog("Error loading metric list': \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        //return nil
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shouldn't have been using RKObjectManager.sharedManager().postObject

This caused the previous values to get overwritten or interfered with.

I switched

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().postObject
```

With

```
objectManager!.postObject
```

Comment: In what way? You mean you have multiple managers so you should have been using `objectManager` instead of `RKObjectManager.sharedManager` ?

Comment: @Wain correct, I updated my answer with what I switched around.